# How to use one handler for multiple objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As shown in [this jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/Se39G/):

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
<p>Drag me 1</p>
</div>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
<p>Drag me 2</p>
</div>
```

with handler:

```
$(function() {
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
});
```

How can I make the 2nd square draggable as the 1st one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id's should be unique. Use class selector. Try this:

```
$(function() {
$( ".ui-widget-content" ).draggable();
});
```

Ref: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Se39G/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use class selector instead of id selector. You have duplicate ids on page, and id selector will only select first element.Try this:

```
 $(function() {
  $( ".ui-widget-content" ).draggable();
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Se39G/1/)**